# IOS Touch Event Radius

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, mobile

For a React Native IOS, how do I get the touch radius of a touch event emitted from a button? So is there a way to get radiusX/Y as I can do that in Web: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events.

Comment: Hi Ningyu Chen, welcome to stackoverflow! Please add more details on what you are trying to achieve. – Because as far as I understand, there is no such thing as a touch radius. iOS recognizes touch events at precise screen locations (with a 'radius' of 1 point). And if there is a button at the touch location: bingo, button tapped. – So: what do you mean by 'Touch Event Radius'?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use the UITouch object, and here is the documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitouch.